# Why new type of schema-markup caused links get unindex in google search engine?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, schema.org, google-index

My question is about the type of schema markup.

[Here](https://lamtakam.com/dictionaries/en/399330/test) is my website which is a dictionary. from the first until 2 weeks ago, the type of my website (in schema markup) was specified as `dataset`.

2 weeks ago, google said, from now on, review (yellow stars under website in google search result) is not acceptable for `dataset` type anymore. So, I've changed its type to `book` and now stars are shown for my website links in google search result. BUT, google is keep unindexing my indexed URLs. See:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what should I do to make those links indexed again back?

Comment: What are you screenshots supposed to show?  It looks like the numbers haven't changed much, most of your pages are valid with only a handful of errors?

Comment: When you say "unindexed", do you mean that Google isn't indexing the page at all, or that it isn't showing a rich snippet for the page based on the Schema?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your site has information about books at all.   Or does it?   If it doesn't you are just abusing structured data to try to get rich snippets.